# Knockout.JS computed observable live search

Tags: search, knockout.js

I am working on a live search feature for a knockout.js proof of concept. The ko.computed array doesn't return anything when I believe it should. Any help is definitely appreciated. Here is a jsfiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umPh7/14/)

```
self = this;
self.query = ko.observable('benefits');
self.samplesharepoint = [
    { title: "benefits", url: "www.benefits.com", sites: "branchburg, branford", topics: "benefits", tagged: "false" },
    { title: "health", url: "www.health.com", sites: "indy, laval", topics: "health", tagged: "false"},
    { title: "benefits", url: "www.benefits.com", sites: "ponce, genentech", topics: "benefits", tagged: "false"}
    ];
debugger;
self.pageLinks = ko.observableArray(self.samplesharepoint);
self.computedPageLinks = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.pageLinks, function(item) {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the typical knockout mistake: because `self.pageLinks` and `self.query` are observables - which are functions - you need to call them without any arguments to get their values.

So change your computed to:

```
self.computedPageLinks = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.pageLinks(), function(item) {
        return item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
});
```

Note the `()` after `self.pageLinks()` and `self.query()`

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2q8Gn/).

You can read more about observables and computeds in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Comment: Thank you. That was fast and much appreciated. Is there a reason why it fails silently? I can't find an error anywhere.

Comment: It fails silently because the `ko.observableArray` is a function without any formal arguments and because every function has a `length` property - which is the number of the formal arguments - the `ko.utils.arrayFilter` think that your `self.pageLinks` is an array with the `length = 0` so it does not even start the iteration...